# Error in change of projection from Lat/Long to UTM

Tags: qgis, dem

Why does the the DEM when converted to UTM Zone 43N system give all values as 0 in QGIS? I followed the standard procedure of saving the parent layer and then assigning the CRS. When I open the same in ENVI, after editing the header and reassigning the projection of the parent layer, I can see that the units are in metres, but the same when opened in QGIS renders geographic lat/lon system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reproject a DEM data to UTM projection in a correct way, go to `Raster → Projections → Warp (Reproject)`

[image]

- Select the Input File (DEM File).
- In the Output File: Give a new name to save the output
- Source SRS is the spatial reference system of the source DEM. In this example, it is EPSG:4326 (it means WGS 84)
- Check the Target SRS (the target projection): click on Select and choose UTM with correct zone or any desired projection with a meter unit
- Resample Method: Select Bilinear or Cubic. Here Cubic is selected.
- Click OK.

Comment: Thanks, While this shows the layer SRS as UTM, when I use the identifier to find the x and y coordinate it still shows in lat/lon. Thanks, this was due to the present data frame.

Comment: When you finish the projection, load it in a new QGIS file to read it correctly. The identify tool may still reading the data in lat/long because the CRS of the project is still in WGS 84.